# Is there a feature to remove error message

Tags: r

Following code in R shiny application (Server side) gives the result as shown below. But can we make this error message disable? Like we do no need any message to be shown. Can we achieve this?

```
options(shiny.sanitize.errors = TRUE)
```

Result in Console (In Red)

```
Error : An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification
```

Expected result :

or

```
"No table" (The user can type anything he needs?)
```

Comment: If you set it to `FALSE`, the user will see the error message. Docs: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sanitize-errors.html I suggest fixing the issue rather than suppressing it. Having said that, the docs cover the usecases you're likely to encounter

Comment: Thanks and I agree with you. But Can we not remove it completely. Like nothing should be displayed. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, sorry. As mentioned in the docs, you can throw it to your users if it's a safe error

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @nopassport1, the best option is to prevent the error in the first place.

Alternatively, on a case-by-case basis you can remove the error warning by wrapping code in a `try(x,silent = TRUE)` function.

```
> try(1+"a")
Error in 1 + "a" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> try(1+"a",silent = TRUE)
>
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me a little. But unfortunately I get ````Error in Summary.factor(structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), : ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors```` error now in black. The original error was ````Error:‘sum’ not meaningful for factors```` that too in red